# ElasticMapReduce: Specified Availability Zone is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I tried to use EMR in Oregon region so I used "us-west-2" as availability zone in run_job_flow and I got the following error:

```
Error response for action RunJobFlow: Sender/ValidationError; Specified Availability Zone is not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"us-west-2" is the name of a region and NOT the name of an availability zone.

Use either "us-west-2a" or "us-west-2b"

Comment: I think I had tried those as well. Based on my limited search, it looks like when you are not using Virginia there are some other parameters to specify.

Comment: Or the client tool I am using (Net::Amazon::EMR) is not behaving well.

Comment: AWS requests are made to a particular region. If you try to start a jobflow in us-west-2a but make the API call to the us-east-1 endpoint, it will fail(us-east-1 has no knowledge of us-west-2).

You must make your request against the us-west-2 endpoint.

var emrClient =AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonElasticMapReduceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

Comment: I finally learned that there is an endpoint parameter in the new method of the perl module. thanks!